# Sum of 2 $C^*$-subalgebras is a subalgebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $B,C$ two $C^*$-subalgebras of $A$. It is well-known that if $C$ is a closed ideal of $A$, then $B+C$ is a $C^*$-algebra of $A$.

This makes me think that in general $B+C$ need not be a $C^*$-subalgebra, but I couldn't find any counterexample. I guess we already have a problem because $B+C$ need not be an algebra. Are there any concrete examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $M_2(\mathbb C)$, take
$$
B=\biggl\{\begin{bmatrix} b&0\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}:\ b\in\mathbb C\biggr\},\qquad C=\biggl\{\begin{bmatrix}c&c\\ c&c
\end{bmatrix}:\ c\in\mathbb C\biggr\}.
$$
Then $B+C$ is not an algebra, since it doesn't contain $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

For an abelian example, $A=\mathbb C^3$, and
$$
B=\{(b,b,0):\ b\in\mathbb C\},\qquad C=\{(0,c,c):\ c\in\mathbb C\}.
$$
Then
$$
B+C=\{(b,b+c,c):\ b,c\in\mathbb C\}
$$
is not an algebra, because
$$
(0,1,0)=(1,1,0)(0,1,1)\in BC\setminus (B+C). 
$$